# Please help me understand SQL quarter logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand the SQL logic in these statements...

Like in the first statement, I don't get how returning 478 (as of today) returns 2019-07-01 00:00:00.000...?  Please help me understand the logic here.

```
SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)-- First day of last quarter
SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))-- Last day of last quarter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down what is happening in that first statement:

If we just run the inner `DATEDIFF`:

`SELECT DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE())`

this returns the number of quarters between 0 (1900-01-01) and todays date (19th November 2019), the answer being **479**

Now to understand the outer `DATEADD`:

if we look at the syntax of `DATEADD` at [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) its:

`DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`

In your statement `SELECT DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)`

the datepart is `qq` (quarter)

The number is `DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1` we know from above that the `DATEDIFF` equates to 479, then subtract 1 = **478**

the date is `0` (1900-01-01)

So therefore your query is "add 478 quarters to 1900-01-01" which gives you the first date of that quarter: **2019-07-01**

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server. As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), "qq" sets the unit to a quarter.

`DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE())` gets the number of quarters since the 0th quarter, or Q1 of the year 1900.

As of now, we are in quarter 479. If you subtract 1, we get the previous quarter, 478. Quarter 478 starts on 2019-07-01.

As for your second query, `SELECT DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))`,

The portion below retrieves the current quarter. Since we are simply adding quarters to Q0, this gives us the first day of the current quarter.

```
DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE())
```

Then, `DATEADD(dd, -1...` subtracts a day from that to get the last day of the previous quarter.

Comment: thank you for addressing the second statement.  That makes sense!